# setState not updating value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, setstate

I have an `onClick()` for an `react-photo-gallery` based image selector (the `onClick()` is based on the `selectPhoto(event, obj)` function shown in the `react-photo-gallery` example code at https://codesandbox.io/s/o7o241q09?from-embed).

My adapted version of the code has been adapted to include a counter for the number of images selected (so that, for example, I can dynamically provide a download function to users *if* selected>0)

My code looks like this:

```
  selectPhoto(event, obj) {
    let photos = this.state.apiItems;
    photos[obj.index].selected = !photos[obj.index].selected;
    this.setState({ apiItems: photos });
    let localSelectedCount=0;
    this.state.apiItems.forEach(function(pVal,pIndex) {
            if (pVal.selected) {
                localSelectedCount = localSelectedCount + 1;
            }
    });
    this.setState({selectedImagesCount:localSelectedCount});
    console.log(localSelectedCount);
    console.log(this.state.selectedImagesCount);
    //
  }
```

And at the top of my class, I define the initial state:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        selectedImagesCount:0,
        apiItems: []
    };
    this.selectPhoto = this.selectPhoto.bind(this);
}
```

The problem I am encounering is that `localSelectedCount` increments and decrements perfectly.  However `this.state.selectedImagesCount` is always lagging by one.

So, for example, if I select one image and then deselect one image, the `console.log()` will output :

```
1
0
0
1
```

When the expected output is, of course :

```
1
1
0
0
```

I am using Node v10.14.1 and React 16.6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React work this way. The setState call is async. When the next render triggered all previous setState will finished.
You can add a callback to setState. It will called when setState is taken place. If you place your log there it will display the right value.

```
this.setState({selectedImagesCount:localSelectedCount}, () => console.log(this.state.selectedImagesCount));
```

Comment: That works, but are you essentially saying I can't trust the state elsewhere in my code value unless a render has taken place in the intervening period ?

Comment: State handling is basically for updating values for render. That's why it triggers render. React often wait more than one setState and trigger render together. Usually the state is updated together in one step. If you want to use a previously updated state value in a setState you can always use the setSate with function parameter this way you get a up to date version of the state. setState(currentState => {...})

Comment: Great. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`this.state` shouldn't be used together with `setState`. Since state updates are asynchronous, this may result in race conditions.

State [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is supposed to address the problem:

```
...
this.setState({ apiItems: photos });
this.setState(state => {
  let localSelectedCount=0;
  // is a good use case for array reduce
  state.apiItems.forEach(function(pVal,pIndex) {
        if (pVal.selected) {
            localSelectedCount = localSelectedCount + 1;
        }
  })
  return {selectedImagesCount:localSelectedCount};
});
```

Another problem with asynchronous updates is that there's race condition with `console.log`. `setState` updates the value but not at the moment when `console.log` is called. This is what callback argument is for. It should be:

```
...
this.setState({ apiItems: photos });
this.setState(state => {
  let localSelectedCount=0;
  // is a good use case for array reduce
  state.apiItems.forEach(function(pVal,pIndex) {
        if (pVal.selected) {
            localSelectedCount = localSelectedCount + 1;
        }
  })
  return {selectedImagesCount:localSelectedCount};
}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.selectedImagesCount);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about reduce ! Will look into that !